# How provide authenticatioon to check username and password for Soap based webservices

Tags: java, web-services, authentication, soap

I am working on SOAP based web services. I want to check for credentials.

```
@WebService(name="Helloworld",portName="HelloworldPort", serviceName = "Helloworld", targetNamespace="http://Helloworld.com/webservices")

@SOAPBinding(style = SOAPBinding.Style.RPC, use= SOAPBinding.Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle= SOAPBinding.ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)

public class Helloworld   {   

    public String sayHello(@WebParam(name="name")String name) {

        return "hello "+name;


    }

}
```

I have read some where that we can use `USERNAME_PROPERTY, and PASSWORD_PROPERTY` to services.

It seems it is Basic http authentication.

I don't know how to accommodate it in service as well as in client.
 Can some one tell me how to achieve it.

Thanks.

Comment: I think authentication is a database related thing. Write the code for it. And client side will not do that.

Comment: @Mawia. I want to do Basic authentication jax ws